# Texture Warping Shader: Polar to Rectangular Coordinates

Tags: opengl, math, shader, transformation

I am writing a 2D game using OpenGL and I have planned a shadow casting algorithm which needs a transformation of a texture from Polar Coordinates to Rectangular Coordinates. The desired effect is the following:

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

I know the formulas for converting coordinates between both Polar and Rectangular systems but I am having problems on writing the shader to achieve the desired effect.

My shader receives a texture as an input and should draw the warped texture to the screen. I planned the following (knowing that the fragment shader acts upon one fragment at a time):

1. Find the coordinates of the current fragment using gl_FragCoord.xy
2. Determine r and theta that correspond to the point (x, y).
3. Transform r and theta into texture_x and texture_y (which will be used to sample the texture)
4. Transfer the sampled pixel to the current fragment

My final result is the same input texture rotated 90 degrees clock-wise. I think that I'm missing something on step 3. I might be just getting the same x and y of the current fragment, because I'm simply using both the transform and inverse transform formulas.
How should I proceed to get the expected result?

Here is my shader:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main() {

  vec2 fragCoords = gl_FragCoord.xy - vec2(128, 128); //shift the coordinates so that 0, 0 is in the center of the screen (the final texture is 256 * 256)
  fragCoords /= vec2(256, 256);
  float r = sqrt(pow(fragCoords.x, 2) + pow(fragCoords.y, 2));
  float theta = atan(fragCoords.y, fragCoords.x);

  if (fragCoords.y/fragCoords.x <= 0.5 && fragCoords.y/fragCoords.x >= -0.5) {
    r *= 1/(256*sin(theta));
  } else {
    r *= 1/(0.5*256*cos(theta));
  }

  vec2 texCoords = vec2(r, theta);
  vec4 texFrag = texture2D(tex, texCoords);

  gl_FragColor = texFrag * vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your shader you're first translating into polar coordinates

```
float r = sqrt(pow(fragCoords.x, 2) + pow(fragCoords.y, 2));
float theta = atan(fragCoords.y, fragCoords.x);
```

and then you't translating them back into cartesian

```
float tX = r * sin(theta); 
float tY = r * cos(theta);
```

You want to stay in polar coordinates, so just plug `r` and `theta` into the texture coordinates

```
vec2 texCoords = vec2(r , theta);
vec4 texFrag = texture2D(tex, texCoords);
```

However by the looks of the images you pasted there's some renormalization step involved, so that `(r, theta)` will cover a rectangular area. If I'm not entirely mistaken, then r is scaled by the distance it takes a ray from the center-bottom to intersect with the rectangular area. If we assume theta=0 to be straight up, then for the range [-atan(0.5)…atan(0.5)] it's scaled by 1/(height*sin(theta)) and outside that range by 1/(0.5*width*cos(theta))

Comment: Should I get something next to what I expect without doing the normalization? I tried it (just using r and theta right away) and the result was not near what I expected. Afterwards I tried adding the scaling factors and I also didn't seem to work. Should I post code?

Comment: @Thiago: It really depends on where you place the origin of your coordinate system. If you put the polar coordinates just as they are into the texture coordinates, there will be a vastly different outcome, yes. But by changing the origin and base vectors (namely the direction of the theta=0 base) it can be achieved. However I myself had to tinker an hour or so with it.